# Returning an object from JQuery.each() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this code in JavaScript

```
lastUpdated: 1492665454,
  items:

  [
    $.each(objectStory, function(key, value) {
      //key + ": " + value ;
      //console.log(value)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
      //document.write(sitem);

      return JSON.stringify(value);
    }),
  ]

}]
```

the console.log is print the object as I wanted but the return function doesn't work. the data came from json file using ajax call .
this is the return of consolg log

```
{"id":"87","type":"image","src":"url/IMG_2363.MOV"}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can't return a value from `$.each` afaik; it's meant purely for carrying out side effects. Did you mean to use `map`?

Comment: `$.each` doesn't return anything. Do you really want to convert objects to strings? Or do you simply want to convert an object of objects to an array of objects? Or is `objectStory` already an array of objects (in which case you don't have to do anything)? Please explain what you are actually trying to achieve here (see [ask]).

Comment: What is the contents of `objectStory`, and what is the output you're expecting. There would seemingly be several ways to achieve what you need (spread syntax, `map()`, `forEach()`, etc) but the most appropriate depends on your goal.

Comment: use map instead of .each()

Answer (score 2):

`$.each` returns object that it was called with (for chaining with other methods), not string as you would wish. When you need result you should use [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/)`. Please take a look at the snippet showing the difference:

```js
var objectStory = {
 k1: 1,
 k2: 2,
 k3: 3
}

var eachResult = $.each(objectStory, function(key, value) {
  return JSON.stringify(value);
});

var mapResult = $.map(objectStory, function(value) {
  return JSON.stringify(value);
});

console.log(eachResult);
console.log(mapResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In your code you should assign value to key `items` this way:

```
var obj = {
    // other fields
    items: $.map(objectStory, function(value) {
       return JSON.stringify(value);
    })
};
```

Otherwise you would have nested arrays under your `items` key.